# If A is not invertible, can it still be diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, diagonalization

Looking through some properties of my Linear Algebra textbook, I found out that even if a matrix $A$ is invertible, it is not always diagonalizable.

However, if now a matrix $A$ is not invertible, can it be diagonalizable ?

Comment: The answer lies in how many distinct eigenvectors you can make

Comment: The zero matrix is diagonal; is it invertible?

Comment: For a simple answer, yes. E.g. $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Can you write down an inverse of the general diagonal matrix $\pmatrix{\lambda_1&&\\&\ddots&\\&&\lambda_n}$? What conditions must the $\lambda_a$ satisfy in order for the matrix to have an inverse?